# How to keep service running between fragments

Tags: android, android-service

I have multiple Activities extending a base FragmentActivity class. One of the activities is running a service which needs to be available all the time. Now when I switch between activities, the Activitiy's `onDestroy()` is called. Do I unbind the service here? I do not want to unbind it as my service is running and I want it to continue.

The other thing is that I have a receiver that is receiving data from the BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) device and the service is for the BLE connection. Do I unregister the receiver? I do not want to do that either as I want this receiver to continue in the background.

EDIT:

```
    class MyActivity{


           private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           }
```

EDIT:

In manifest:

```
     <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
           <intent-filter>
            <action   android:name="com.directed.carcookie.mGattUpdateReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Error: Exported receiver does not require permission?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what is it that you are trying to accomplish with the `Service` because you didn't supply a lot of information but for long background services why not use [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)?

If you are using regular `Service` You are probably using `onBind()` method. why not using [startService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent))?

For example:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyIntentService.class);
getActivity().startService(serviceIntent)
```

If those 2 methods do not suite you please supply more information

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending from `Service` and using `Context.startService()`and you want your service to keep going , just return `START_STICKY` in your `onStartCommand`. This way, your service will only stop when you explicitly call `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> For started services, there are two additional major modes of operation they can decide to run in, depending on the value they return from onStartCommand(): START_STICKY is used for services that are explicitly started and stopped as needed, while START_NOT_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT are used for services that should only remain running while processing any commands sent to them.

Comment: I did that and it is running fine but then when I switch between the other activity and return back not always but some time I get an error that the receiver is not unregistered and if I unregister the receiver I get the bind error. But I do not want to unregister the receiver as well as it is receiving messages as the service is running.

Comment: Why don't you register those in your manifest? This would allow you to receive data even when your app is not running

Comment: its implemented as in https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/DeviceControlActivity.html , it is not extending it

Comment: Here is shown how to do it via manifest: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: even he is doing dynamically when you look at mMessageReceiver he is registering in his activity